# Asking the user to think of, and write down, a number between 1 and 1,000,000 in java

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

Hi guys so I'm working on writing a program that's asking a user to think of and write down a number between 1 and 1,000,000.

then it asks questions like "Is it greater than 500000?", and the user answers "Yes" or "yes" or "no  or "NO", or "Got It!" now this where I'm stuck at. I don't know how to get it to ask that questions 
this is the code i got so far :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Questions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Questions");
       String S = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 and    1,000,000");
       int i = 1000000;
       if (i>500000){

    }
}
```

how do i use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` to ask questions and get answers ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean how just change `"Enter a number between 1 and 1,000,000"` to `"Is it greater than 500000?"`

Comment: I need to put the 500000 in a variable after String S = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 and    1,000,000"); that's asking is it greater than 1,000,000

Comment: If you have problems getting this GUI to work, you maybe want to take a step back and write a console application, doing the same thing.

Comment: Does the user actually provide the correct answer, or do you rely on binary search eventually narrowing the range down?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `showConfirmDialog()` to ask a yes or no question...Here is an example you would need to change the values as these are hard coded but you should be able to figure out how to put this in a loop and change values dynamically based upon user entry:

```
int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Is 500,000 your number?", "Question", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
if(answer == 1)
{
    answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Is 500,000 less than your number?", "Question", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}
```

This way the user doesn't have to type "yes" or "no" or "got it" which will eliminate human error...

```
Yes - will return 0
No -  will return 1
```

The second question will tell u whether there number is lower or higher than the proposed number depending on whether they answer yes or no...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I strongly recommend debugging in the console until your logic is complete, then work on the GUI.

You are basically trying to implement a binary search, where the computer should get the answer right in `log(N)` guesses.

Here is some code to get you started. The GUI should be fairly straightforward. Read the appropriate Javadocs.

```
try (Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);) {
    String input;
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = 1000000; 
    int mid;
    while (true) {
        mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
        System.out.printf("Is it equal to %d?\n", mid);
        if (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("Got it!")) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Is it greater than %d?\n", mid); 
            input = k.nextLine();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                lo = mid;
            } else {
                hi = mid;
            }
        }
    } 
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: it is possible to use JOptionPane instead of scanner?

Comment: Yes, but you should get the game itself working first. The other comments have good advice on the GUI stuff, which is also fairly easily searchable.

Answer (score 0):

First you should change S to an integer because you're asking the user to enter an integer. Second, assuming the program is supposed to try to guess the number, you would start with 500,000 and keep guessing in halves until you get the entered number (it looks like you got this part). So here is an outline (I'm not quite sure what the exact syntax is for JOptipnPane but you can find commands for input and output):

```
String YesOrNo = JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog ("is the number higher than 500,000? ")
```

If YesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase ("yes") then guess 750,00 next if no guess 250,000 next

This is an outline see if you can get the rest if not comment for further help

Comment: Not sure why it posted two answers I edited my answer below and it posted a new one... sorry for the repeat

Answer (score -1):

First you should change `S` to `int` because you are asking the user to enter an integer. Second, assuming the program is supposed to try to guess the number, you would start with 500,000 and keep guessing in halves until you get the entered number (it looks like you got this part). So here is an outline (I am not quite sure what the exact syntax is for `JOptipnPane` is but you can find commands for input and output):

```
String yesOrNo = JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog("is the number higher than 500,000? ")
```

If `yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")` then guess 750,00 next if no guess 250,000 next

This is an outline see if you can get the rest. If not comment for further help.

Comment: The OP does not want the user to enter an integer. Rather, the user should enter a series of "yes"/"no" responses, which should definitely be Strings.

Comment: Yes after they enter a number (integer) the program will try to find it then it will need yes or no as string like I have String S. If you look at the example the OP was asking to enter a number and storing it in a string S. I was saying change that S to an integer. Then later in the program my S was a string as you see in my answer. I will change my S to something else so that it is more clear.

Comment: Ah, I see. The OP's design has some issues. I took the written description literally, where the program doesn't know your number but you continually feed in Higher or Lower input. Leave it up to OP to clarify.